# How to set up my try and catch block?

Tags: java, class, exception, try-catch

everyone I am a beginner programmer with a little problem on my hands. I am trying to make test statements for one of my classes for a project and have come across a problem. I can't seem to get my try and catch block to work. I have tried using super and inheritance and everything I can think of, but i can;t get it to work. I also can't tell if I'm testing my class or not. I'm so confused on how to set up a try and catch for this class and help would be nice. Thank you so much in advance. Below is my code:

```
 public Resistor (double resistancevalue, double tolerancevalue, double powerrating)throws Exception {
    if (resistancevalue <= 0){
        throw new Exception ("The resistance value must be greater than zero.");
    }
    if (tolerancevalue <=0 || tolerancevalue>=1){
        throw new Exception ("The tolerance value must be between zero and one (not incusive).");

    }
    if (powerrating >=0){
        throw new Exception("The power rating must be greater than zero.");
    }
    else{
        this.resistancevalue=resistancevalue;
        this.tolerancevalue = tolerancevalue;
        this.powerrating = powerrating;
    }

}
public double getResistanceValue(){
    return resistancevalue;
}
double miniResistance(){
    double Minir = resistancevalue*(1.0-tolerancevalue);
    return Minir;
}
double maxResistance(){
    double Maxr= resistancevalue*(1.0+tolerancevalue);
    return Maxr;
}
```

Test class:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    //Tesing the resistor class
    //testing to see if the expection is caught when the resistence value is less than 0

    double tolerancevalue = 0.5;
    double powerrating = 1;

    try {
        double resistancevalue=1;



        System.out.println("Exception Failed");

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You haven't made any actual call to the `Resistor` constructor. The following code behaves as expected:

```
try {
    double resistancevalue=1;

    // the following line will throw an exception...
    Resistor r = new Resistor(resistancevalue, tolerancevalue, powerrating);

    System.out.println("Exception Failed");

} catch (Exception e) {

    // the exception is caught and printed here
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

}


// prints "The power rating must be greater than zero."
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the Resistor constructor inside of the try-catch statement.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO code application logic here
//Tesing the resistor class
//testing to see if the expection is caught when the resistence value is less than 0

double tolerancevalue = 0.5;
double powerrating = 1;

try {
    double resistancevalue=1;

    Resistor testResistor = new Resistor(resistancevalue,tolerancevalue, powerrating);  

    System.out.println("Exception Failed");

} catch (Exception e) {

    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try and catch work if there is an exception in your program (body of try{here}). if there is not an exception they will not work. That is how they work